# Static files with bootstraps directory

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I thought it would be easier to download bootstrap and adjust it to my code, instead of messing about a cdn. So I downloaded bootstrap and my directory looks like this.

[image]

My static directory is properly (I think) setup since my style.css and maps.js are working fine.

In my base.html I reference the files with:

```
The old way <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
<script src="{% static 'maps.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.7' %}"></script>
```

The static boostrap-3.3.7 is not working. The cdn worked however. My question is how would my static import look to have this setup with the bootstrap directory properly work?

I'm sorry if it's a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include a complete directory into your HTML, which is impossible. You should adjust the path in `{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.7' %}` to the location of the actual file you need.

```
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/js/boostrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Note, don't forget to add the css file too, you need to include them both individually. Which will probably be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap-3.3.7/dist/css/boostrap.min.css' %}"/>
```

Comment: Alright, I'll just have to add a few lines with the imports. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You actually don't need the entire bootsrap directory in static. Everything you need should be in the 'dist' directory.